# How to show the New icon when somebody replies in a discussion board?

Tags: 2007, discussion-board

Is it possible to show the New icon when somebody replies in a discussion board?

If I create a new topic, the New icon is shown. After the default 2 days the icon's gone. I'd like to show it again if somebody replies to the topic, or any form of notification.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

All right. Here is what I did. I followed [Dribbel suggestion of adding a column](https://sharepoint.stackexchange.com/questions/11102/show-the-new-icon-when-somebody-replies-in-a-discussion-board/11139#11139) with the last -updated date to the view. Then, using JQuery, I looked for all these columns and made some javascript math to check if there were new comments or not. Last, I replaced the content of this column with a custom made "new cmnt" icon or clear the contents of it accordingly.

Kind of a hack, but it works.

Answer (score 2):

You can add a column to the view that lists the date of the latest response.